# Globally edit color of TextButton widgets in an AppBar actions list?

Tags: flutter, colors, themes, flutter-appbar

In my root file I have:

```
theme: ThemeData(
  appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
    textTheme: TextTheme(
      button: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
    ),
  ),
),
```

and in my custom AppBar file:

```
return AppBar(
  automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
  actions: <Widget>[
    TextButton(
      child: Text('Sign in'),
      onPressed: () {},
    ),
  ],
);
```

but the text remains the default light blue-ish color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `TextButton` in your AppBar but not defining its theme in your code. You need to define the [TextButtonTheme](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextButtonTheme-class.html) in order to change the color of the text of your TextButton. Like this.

```
ThemeData(
 textbuttonTheme: TextbuttonThemeData(
   style: Textbutton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.teal)),
  ),
```

Comment: This affects all other TextButton. Is there any way to change the color of TextButton only in AppBar?

Comment: Yes, The TextButton for which you want to change the color specifically just use its style property. This way the changes will be only for the specific button.

Answer (score 1):

```
return MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
      style: TextButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.black)
    )
  ),
  home: MyWidget(),
);
```

**Migrate FlatButton to TextButton**

```
return MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
        primary: Colors.black87,
        minimumSize: Size(88, 36),
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
        shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(2.0)),
        ),
      )
    )
  ),
  home: MyWidget(),
);
```